# Controlling UberCart checkout pane hook priorities

Tags: drupal, hook, ubercart

I'm using Drupal 6.15 with ubercart 2.x and I'm trying to implement ubercart's hook_checkout_pane() to override their default uc_cart_checkout_pane(). My goal is to disable some of the default checkout panes - customer information and order comments.

I made a function my_module_checkout_pane() in my_module.module and it does get called, but the uc_cart version seems to be generating what's actually rendered.

I understand why both functions get called and I can change the order they're called in by modifying my module's weight in the system table, but doing so doesn't seem to affect what ends up on the page. Whether my_module's function is called first or second, the uc_cart version is what's rendered. The only way I can get my function to affect the page is to actually alter uc_cart_checkout_pane() so it doesn't return any output but that's not a "good" solution.

Is there some other place I need to do something to make Drupal favor my hook implementation over uc_carts'? Alternatively, is there another way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can enable or disable checkout panes in "[Checkout settings](http://www.ubercart.org/docs/user/8396/checkout_settings)".

btw: no need to alter module weights, you can do this with pane weights.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken, hook_checkout_pane is for creating new checkout panes, not overriding default ones. Seems like you'd use hook_checkout_pane to make your own pane and just use that instead? See http://www.ubercart.org/forum/development/11698/alter_checkout_panes

Apologies if I'm mistaken.

Comment: That could work if there was an answer to the question posed in the third post - how do you disable the original panes? Post #2 alludes to the possibility but doesn't say how to do it. I tried something like hook_checkout_pane_alter but couldn't make that work. I'm not sure if it's something that exists or if it's just something the poster thinks should exist.

Comment: you can enable or disable checkout panes in "Checkout settings" <http://www.ubercart.org/docs/user/8396/checkout_settings >. btw: no need to alter module weights, you can do this with pane weights.

Comment: Thank you! I'd looked at the checkout settings but didn't see the checkout panes sub-menu.

Comment: so should i make my comment an answer (which you can accept)?